# Did the action happen?

Tags: past-tense, clauses, subordinate-clauses

Here are the sentences:

***I needed to wait until my girlfriend came.*(Did his girlfriend come?)**

***In the past, If it rained, I wouldn't go outside.*(The condition means "it already rained or it would rain?)**

***Last year, I always had waited 30 minutes before the bus came.*(This means finally the bus came, but I had waited 30 minutes before it came,right?)**

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't rely on these providing any precise information about the action. They are valid, natural phrases in English, but not definitive in the way you might be requiring. This would, for example, make them difficult to translate _from_ English.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit of ambiguity in many of those sentences, but their usual interpretation is as follows:

> I needed to wait until my girlfriend came.

Because the sentence did *not* go on to say "but she never did.", you'd have to assume that she came.

> In the past, if it rained, I wouldn't go outside.

The sense here is definitely if it was currently raining, or had recently rained, rather than that it *would* rain. If the speaker meant "threatening to rain", the sentence would have included phrases like "looked like rain", "forecast for rain", or other future words - even though it was a past-tense statement.

> Last year, I always had waited 30 minutes before the bus came.

Yes, the bus always came, and the speaker had waited for 30 minutes each time.

Comment: It is possible that the bus didn't arrive and the speaker went home. Why else tell us that he would wait for 30 minutes?

Comment: @MickSharpe Because there was no condition in the sentence? "waited fruitlessly" or "waited for 30 minutes hoping that", or other such negative terms. Given minimal sentences like those, you have to assume the implied result.

Comment: So the only correct interpretation is that it was his policy to wait for up to 30 minutes but the bus always came within that time? I can see that in the second example, we must assume that it did rain at some time but it seems to me that there is more than one way to account for the phrase *30 minutes*.

Comment: ...or is the correct interpretation *I always had to wait 30 minutes for the bus to arrive*?

Comment: @MickSharpe I like your last sentence, yes. Personally I'd've done something else for those 30 minutes - or stated it as "the bus was always 30 minutes late, but I daren't risk getting there after the scheduled arrival time"

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I think the first one maybe a litttle bit different."He needed to wait her girlfriend until she came"(maybe finally she didn't come, but the boy needed to wait until she came in the past.like condition) And the second sentence should be without ang doubt. But I can't understand the third, can I use the third sentence to express that someone left?(without saying any condition)?

Comment: If the person left after waiting for the bus and it still didn't come, then the whole sentence needs to be different: "Last year, I always waited 30 minutes for the bus to come before giving up." In other words, they stayed at the bus stop and either got on the bus, or waited 30 minutes and left again.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help! But what about the first sentence? He neede to wait until his grilfriend was back.(maybe finally his girlfriend didn't come at last, but he needed to wait)

Comment: Of course he needed to wait for his girlfriend! That's what girlfriends need - for their boyfriends to wait for them. But if the sentence wants to say that she may not have arrived, it needs to say so. At the moment, it suggests that of _course_ she came, and wasn't playing games with him... "I needed to wait until my girlfriend came - even if she didn't turn up."

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for your help! That means the first one is ambiguous, not clear enough. It just mentioned that the man needed to wait. We don't know his girlfriend came or not. And we even have no idea if the man waited. Maybe he didn't, so they broke up. Haha, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

All that you are telling us is that it was your habit to wait until your girlfriend came, &etc. Maybe your girlfriend always came, maybe she only came sometimes, or maybe she never came at all. We simply don't know because you haven't told us. You cannot rely on your readers to make correct assumptions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But that is the first sentence, what about the second and the third?

Comment: See John's answer. It is probably better than mine. The only thing that I will stick by is my last sentence.